# Help with a inequality

Tags: matrices, analysis, numerical-calculus

I need to understand this inequality and show if $x^t H x < M ||x||^2$ then $x^t H^t H x < M^2 ||x||^2$ with H is positive definite and $M>0$, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^t H^t H x = (x^t H^t \frac{x x^t}{||x||^2} H x) = \frac{1}{||x||^2} (x^t H x )^t ( x^t H x) \le \frac{1}{||x||^2} (M||x||^2)^t (M||x||^2) = M^2||x||^2 $$

Comment: ohh i see it, i try to sum H^t and not norms, thx u so much friend.

Comment: The first equality isn't correct. E.g. when $x=(1,1)^t$ and $H=\operatorname{diag}(1,2)$, we have $x^tH^tHx=5\ne\frac{9}{2}=x^t H^t\frac{xx^t}{\|x\|^2}Hx$.